# Problems running python tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

when I try to run the tests on this code I am having problems with item, I do not understand what can fail

def fix_me(my_list):

```
if len(my_list) % 2:  # imperative code
    new_list = []
    for item in my_list:
        for element in item:
            new_list = new_list.append(element)
else:  # functional code
    new_list = [element for element in my_list for element in item]

# sorting hierarchy:
#   1. desc by x % 5
#   2. desc by x
return new_list.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x % 5 + x/(max(new_list)*2))
```

Arguments: [ [ 3, 4 ], [ 2, 6 ] ]

output:
Error: free variable 'item' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
Tipo de error: NameError
Lugar: Error en la linea número 9 (" new_list = [element for element in my_list for element in item]")

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to get all the elements into new_list then change

```
new_list = [element for element in my_list for element in item]
```

to

```
new_list = [element for item in my_list for element in item]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension has a problem. It's not right:

```
for element in item
```

From what I understand, you want the *second* element of the lists. So you have to go to `element[1]`; e.g.,

```
new_list = [element[1] for element in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code

```
new_list = new_list.append(element)
```

It should be

```
new_list.append(element)
```

The assignation may give an error when the list is empty